# Mongo Working Set Fit in RAM

Tags: mongodb

Mongo docs ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/)  recommend allocating enough RAM to include the "working set," i.e. documents used by application on a regular basis.

Let's say I have a 50 GB file size for my only database's collection. And the index takes up 5 GB. I need to query across the entire collection, but only query on indexes.

If I only perform queries that will use the index, i.e. no `BasicCursor` queries, is it only necessary to allocate 5 GB RAM rather than 50 GB, the size of my working set?

Comment: No you still need index usage + loaded documents unless they are indexOnly queries

Comment: Oh, so I'd need 5 GB RAM **minimum** simply to search the index in memory. However, I would still need 50 GB RAM total because, without that extra RAM, I'd be performing fast look-ups in RAM, but there'd be IO cost to fetch the rest of the documents (excluding index) from disk?

Comment: Normally the working set is a window of time, about 10 minutes is a good bet, you need to calculate how many documents your looking to access in about 10 minutes. 50 GB RAM is a bit much to house, and the IO won't be too bad if you keep to not page thrashing

Comment: Well, in my case, any of the documents could be searched at any time. Based on your helpful information, sounds like I need 50 GB RAM or at least 5 GB RAM plus SSDs. Care about posting answer for getting credit? Thanks